# Slowness when chaining LINQ queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am doing chaining LINQ queries as show below. I am trying to find out the cause for the slowness of `query.ToList();`. The SQL queries are fast (milliseconds), but the code takes a minute. The reason for chaining is to reuse the repository function.

1. Is there any obvious reasons for slowness here?
2. How could I optimize this ?
3. How can I check the actual SQL query executed when
   running `query.ToList();`?

   ```
   //Client
   var query = _service.GetResultsByStatus(status, bType, tType);
   var result = query.ToList(); //takes a long time to execute 

   //Service function
    public IEnumerable<CustomResult> GetResultsByStatus(string status, string bType, string tType) {
       IEnumerable<CustomResult> result = null;
       result = repo.GetResults(bType).Where(item => item.tStatus == status && (tType == null || item.tType == tType))
           .Select(item => new CustomResult {
              A = item.A,
              B = item.B,
           });
       return result;
   }


   // Repository Function (reused in many places)
   public IEnumerable<my_model> GetResults(string bType) {
        return from p in dbContext.my_model()
            where p.bType.Equals(bType)
            select p;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `.Where(item => item.tStatus == status && (tType == null || item.tType == tType))` and the `.Select` are being done "locally" on your PC... Tons of useless rows and columns are being returned by the SQL to be then "filtered" on your PC.

```
public IEnumerable<my_model> GetResults(string bType) {
     return from p in dbContext.my_model()
         where p.bType.Equals(bType)
         select p;
}
```

Change it to

```
public IQueryable<my_model> GetResults(string bType) {
```

Normally `IEnumerable<>` means "downstream LINQ will be executed locally", `IQueryable<>` means "downstream LINQ will be executed on a server". In this case the `Where` and the `Select` are "downstream" from the transformation of the query in a `IEnumerable<>`. Note that while it is possible (and easy) to convert an `IQueryable<>` to an `IEnumerable<>`, the opposite normally isn't possible. The `AsQueryable<>` creates a "fake" `IQueryable<>` that is executed locally and is mainly useful in unit tests.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. The solution worked like a charm. Thought having IEnumerable was sufficient for deferred execution.

Comment: @devnull `IEnumerable<>` *is* "deferred execution"... "Where" and "When" are orthogonal concepts. Array/List vs IQueryable/IEnumerable are When, IEnumerable vs IQueryavble are Where